# Groovy metaprogramming with Java

Tags: java, groovy, metaprogramming

Say I have a large collection of Java static methods in a class of only static methods.  All of them apply to some type of collection class. How can I scan this class, and using Groovy add each of them to the respective metaclasses?

So a sample might look something like this:

```
public class CollectionUtilities {    
    public static <T> T duplicates(Collection<T> coll) {
       return // some code to isolate the duplicates
    }
}
```

I'd want that to end up so I could call `[1, 2, 2].duplicates()` => [2]

```
Collection.metaClass.duplicates = { -> // replace coll usages with delegate }
```

Has anyone done anything like this?

Any idea of a good way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with categories.  A category can be employed locally as you demonstrated with your answer, or globally via `mixin`.

To add every method of your CollectionUtilities class to Collections at runtime, you can simply do the following:

`Collection.mixin CollectionUtilities`

Answer (score 0):

I've found I can use the 'use' keyword to magically pull in a class like so:

```
use(src.CollectionUtilities) { 
   [1, 2, 3, 3].duplicates() 
} 
=> [3]
```

This is more of a brute force technique, and the code using the methods has to be contained within the clojure, I wonder still if there is a more precise way to do this......